# Dealing with a csv file in which rows have more fields than fieldnames?

Tags: python, csv, formatting

Hello I have a csv file in which row have more fields than fieldnames, e.g.

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5
item1,item2,item3,item4,item5
item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6
item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7
```

As you can see there are items which are "out of bounds" and I am not sure how to put them back in place so they look like this:

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5
item1,item2,item3,item4,item5
item1,item2,item3,item4,item5
item1,item2,item3,item4,item6
item1,item2,item3,item4,item6
item1,item2,item3,item4,item5
item1,item2,item3,item4,item7
```

I simply want to copy the rows which are correct, and place one of the items inside to create a correctly formatted column as the data that is "out of bounds" is still extremely useful to me.

I have tried the CSV module and multiple other methods but to no success, I have managed to isolate the extra fields but the CSV module puts them in some kind of list and it's not easy to read/write from it.

Here is some of the code I tried:

```
with open("log.csv", 'r') as csv_file:
reader1 = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

# Skip Headers
# header = next(reader1)
# print(header, len(header))

# Rows
for row in reader1:
    # Correctly formatted file + out of bounds extras.
    correct_format = "{}\n".format(row)
    print(row)
```

Comment: you need a condition to check the amount of items, then manipulate the last item in each row ```item[-1]``` based on that condition. else just add all items to the row.

Comment: @Aru Hi, When I try item[-1] I get an output consisting only of the last header and nothing else.

Comment: You obviously need to iterate through the rows, each row is a list, and this should definietly give you every last item of each row  ```for row in reader1: print(row[-1])```

Comment: @Aru That is exactly what I have done.

Answer (score 0):

If I run this:

```
with open("exa.csv", 'r') as csv_file:
    reader1 = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    for row in reader1:
        print(row[-1])
```

my output is:

```
column5
item5
item6
item7
```

But there is a lot more work that you have to do, you have to get the length of each row, because each list in your result has exactly 5 items in it. The last item of each row in your result list has to be the last item of the row in your original csv file.

This could be one way to solve the problem:
(the output will be a list with each row as sublist)

```
import csv

result = []

with open("exa.csv", 'r') as csv_file:
    reader1 = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    for row in reader1:
        if len(row) == 5:
            result.append(row)
        
        else:
            new_list = row[:5]
            new_list[-1] = row[-1]
            result.append(new_list)

print(result)
```

My output:

```
[
['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5'], 
['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'], 
['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item6'], 
['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item7']
]
```

Without a file but having a list instead:

```
exa_list = [
["column1","column2","column3","column4","column5"],
["item1","item2","item3","item4","item5"],
["item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","item6"],
["item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","item6","item7"],
]

result = []

for row in exa_list:
    if len(row) == 5:
        result.append(row)
        
    else:
        new_list = row[:5]
        new_list[-1] = row[-1]
        result.append(new_list)

print(result)
```

Comment: Maybe my CSV file itself is screwed up? because I'm getting an output but it is literally of blank items, is there anyway to deal with that?

Comment: I cant tell i am sorry, i  just created a csv file with the example you gave and for me, the iterating process works fine.